# How to differentiate between two labels with an identical "for" attribute?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<label class="my-class" for="_something">Text Number 1</label>
<label class="my-class" for="_something">Number 2 Text</label>
```

Basically I have 2 labels with identical class and also identical for= attributes

I know that I can target the attribute by:

```
label[for="_something"] {
   /* input */
}
```

But how can I differentiate the 2 of them?

Basically I need to use the CSS to hide the second label.

Can I target the attribute by the "name text"? "Number 2 Text" in this example?

Comment: Not possible with CSS.

Comment: Just read his question, mate. He doesn't really want to match a string. He just wanted to hide the second label. Don't overcomplicate it. I know it's cold in Canada. Using jQuery to hide an element in this case is bit of an overkill.

Comment: @TiborB. - You still don't get it, do you?

Answer (score 1):

It IS indeed possible with CSS. Just use `nth-of-type()`.

HTML:

```
<label class="my-class" for="_something">Text Number 1</label>
<label class="my-class" for="_something">Number 2 Text</label>
<label class="my-class" for="_something">Number 3 Text</label>
<label class="my-class" for="_something">Number 4 Text</label>
```

CSS:

```
label[for="_something"]:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/ua91bf0b/

Please note: This is a CSS3 feature, and will not work with some of the old browsers.

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: He wanted to target the 2nd label with identical `class` and `for` tag. This one does that just fine.

Comment: The OP seeks for a selector that will select the element that contains the text **"Number 2 Text"**, which is ofcourse not possible with CSS.

Comment: He said: "Basically I need to use the CSS to hide the second label.
". Please explain me, how would my answer not hide the second label.

Comment: And you forgot to read the next line - _"Can I target the attribute by the "name text" ? "Number 2 Text" in this example ??"_.

Comment: It was just his idea of finding a way to target it at all.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS and I'm almost tempted to downvote this answer simply for your insistence that it is. But instead I will explain: the moment you switch any of the labels or inputs such that they are out of order, the selector will break immediately and you are forced to adjust your selector according to the change. Can you reconcile that with the OP's requirements? I don't think so.

Comment: I see now that you said in the comments above that the OP just wants to hide the second label. While they did say that in their question, they were just pointing to the element in their example. It doesn't necessarily mean you can make that kind of assumption about their markup - and even if you could, it's still incorrect to say that it's possible with CSS if it depends *entirely on the markup* in order to work, and *not CSS*.

Comment: Alternatively we can have OP clarify their question, i.e. whether he really cares about the content or he doesn't. If he just wants to hide everything but the first, then *that* is possible with CSS.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you very much for the effort. Basically I'm running a WP MU with 2 subsites. I am making changes only on the second site ID_2.

So whatever changes I am doing, I use either my custom made plugin activated only on the second site or a Custom CSS plugin again only activated on the second site.

I am trying to avoid editing core files or even functions.php, so the change doesn't affect the main site.

Now I have a front end product submission form and I need to slightly modify it for the second site. So I need to hide some fields that I don't want users to fill up on the subsite.

Comment: Continued .. I've been successful hiding these fields and their labels using the CSS `display: none` attribute.

But now I came across to 2 fields with the exact same class and the exact same for attribute as described in my question.

I need to hide one of the fields and its label, the second one. But how to differentiate them ??

Comment: @TiborB. thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Your solution on label level `label[for="_something"]:nth-of-type()` doesn't seem to work, but I managed to get this sorted using the `:nth-of-type()` function on `div` level. That works great with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the label based on it's text (Number 2 Text) then you need to use jQuery. It's "almost" the same since you use css selectors too in jQuery.

```
$('label[for$="_something"]:contains("2")')
```

this one for example takes the labels where the for tag ends with "_something" (so it's good with 123_something and asd_something too) adn the label text contains "2".

You can make a function for this for easier use:

```
function HideLabel(forattr, texttosearch) {
  $('label[for$="'+forattr+'"]:contains("'+texttosearch+'")').css('display','none');
}
```

And use it like:

```
HideLabel('_something', '2');
```